# Get abbrev-commit for a git branch, cleanly

Tags: git

I need to extract abbreviated commit names for specific git branches. These are typically 7-digit hexadecimal numbers, and they're used by some systems (including Heroku's COMMIT_HASH environment variable) to identify a specific commit.

There's several ugly ways to get an abbreviated commit name, including:

```
$ git log -1 --oneline | awk '{ print $1 }'
d4377e3
$ git describe --always --match ''
d4377e3
```

Is there a cleaner way to get this value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Great question.  I believe are looking for `git-rev-parse`, one of the low level git commands.

```
[jason@star Data]$ git-rev-parse --short github/master
8b81a38
```

Also, if you want the latest commit on current branch, just pass `HEAD` as the parameter.

```
[jason@star Data]$ git-rev-parse --short HEAD
8b81a38
```

Comment: To be *annoyingly* pedantic, `git-rev-parse` is a porcelain command. For scripting purposes, the plumbing command `git rev-list -n1 --abbrev-commit HEAD` should be used instead. But it doesn’t matter ;)

Answer (score 2):

`git log`'s `--pretty-format` option can be used:

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:%h
```

Comment: gives me unrecognised argument

Answer (score 1):

I found [pimping-out-git-log](http://www.jukie.net/bart/blog/pimping-out-git-log) useful.